# Set base rating on woocommerce products

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using this function to set a 5/5 rating on all the woocommerce products:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'get_star_rating', 5 );
    function get_star_rating()
    {
        global $woocommerce, $product;
        $average = $product->get_average_rating();

        echo '<div class="star-rating active"><span style="width:'.( ( 5 / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
    }
```

The problem is that this code is not dynamic: A product will always have 5/5 even if many users rate it with 0/5.

How can I set the "base" rating to be 3/5 to all the products and that if the users rate it, it changes according to the average value?